# IE is 1 pixel too high

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am developing a site to be used in full screen on the browser, at a height of 1080px, on a monitor that's 1920 by 1080 resolution.

In IE the site is 1 pixel too high which means a scroll bar is displayed. An example is below:

```
<html>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .main {
        height: 1080px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="main">
    </div>
</body>
```

Potential solutions (a last resort) are:

1. Set overflow to hidden.
2. Set the height to 1079px.

The site will be utilised as an iframe in another site so I don't wan't to use these solutions and properly fix the issue.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You could use a conditional statement to only target IE, or just set it as 100%?

Comment: I just tested your code in my IE9 browser.  No scroll bars.  Added one more pixel, scroll bars appear.  Which version of IE are you using?  Also, the users might have a status bar turned on; if you wish to make 100% sure the scroll bars won't appear, you probably want overflow to be set to hidden.

Comment: Why not set the height to 100%?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm targeting IE11 only. True about setting overflow to hidden. However my page will be an iframe implemented by other developer's so if I can do it without them having to work for it then that would be good. I can't set the height to 100% as the specification want's a 1080px high page within the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to:

- Set overflow to hidden.
- Set the height to 1079px to allow for the extra height in IE and Firefox.

I didn't want to create browser dependant code so thought the UI could handle being 1079px even though it's an odd number.

On testing at first I thought overflow didn't need to be set as hidden. Some screens were still showing a scroll bar however so better to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--[if IE]>
   .main {
        height: 1079px;
    }
<![endif]-->
<![if !IE]>
   .main {
        height: 1080px;
    }
<![endif]>
```

This seems wrong but it's probably what you're looking for!

Comment: "I'm targeting IE11 only." ... Conditional comments are not supported in IE>9.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu, I didn't know that! And the IE11 comment was left after my answer :)